# gzip compression not working with laravel 5.4 over WAMP

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, gzip, httpd.conf, apache2.4

I am trying to activate gzip compression on WAMP server for laravel 5.4 but its not working. I tested by loading a normal (non-laravel) file and it was working fine but for some reason its not working with laravel. I have tried to add the config into .htaccess in laravel public folder, in vhost config file and in apache httpd conf file with different configurations, but none of it seems to be working.
This is the final config I am using right now in above mentioned files:

```
# Force compression for mangled headers.
# https://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/pushing-beyond-gzipping-25601.html

<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
        RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

# Map certain file types to the specified encoding type in order to
# make Apache serve them with the appropriate `Content-Encoding` HTTP
# response header (this will NOT make Apache compress them!).

# If the following file types wouldn't be served without the appropriate
# `Content-Enable` HTTP response header, client applications (e.g.:
# browsers) wouldn't know that they first need to uncompress the response,
# and thus, wouldn't be able to understand the content.

# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#addencoding

<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddEncoding gzip              svgz
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|html|php|txt|xml)$">
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>

# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

# Compress all output labeled with one of the following media types.

# IMPORTANT: For Apache versions below 2.3.7 you don't need to enable
# `mod_filter` and can remove the `<IfModule mod_filter.c>` & `</IfModule>`
# lines as `AddOutputFilterByType` is still in the core directives.

<IfModule mod_filter.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE "application/atom+xml" \
                                  "application/javascript" \
                                  "application/json" \
                                  "application/ld+json" \
                                  "application/manifest+json" \
                                  "application/rdf+xml" \
                                  "application/rss+xml" \
                                  "application/schema+json" \
                                  "application/vnd.geo+json" \
                                  "application/vnd.ms-fontobject" \
                                  "application/x-font-ttf" \
                                  "application/x-web-app-manifest+json" \
                                  "application/xhtml+xml" \
                                  "application/xml" \
                                  "font/opentype" \
                                  "image/svg+xml" \
                                  "image/x-icon" \
                                  "text/cache-manifest" \
                                  "text/css" \
                                  "text/html" \
                                  "text/javascript" \
                                  "text/plain" \
                                  "text/vtt" \
                                  "text/x-component" \
                                  "text/xml"
</IfModule>
```